# PHP: Iterating through array?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

- I want a function that
  searches through my array, and
  returns all the
  children to a specific node. What is
  the most appropriate way to do this?
  Will recursion be necessary in this case?

I have previously constructed a few quite complex functions that iterates with or without the help of recursion through multi-dimensional arrays and re-arranging them, but this problem makes me completely stuck and I can't just get my head around it...

Here's my array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array (
            [id] => 1
            [parent] => 0

        )

    [2] => Array (
            [id] => 2
            [parent] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array (
            [id] => 3
            [parent] => 2
        )
)
```

UPDATE:

The output which I want to get. Sorry for the bad example, but I'll blame it on lack of knowledge on how to format the stuff I need to do :)

```
function getAllChildren($id) {
    // Psuedocode
    return $array;
}

getAllChildren(1); // Outputs the following:

Array
(
    [2] => Array (
            [id] => 2
            [parent] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array (
            [id] => 3
            [parent] => 2
        )
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$nodes = array( 1   => array (  'id'        => 1,
                                'parent'    => 0
                             ),
                2   => array ( 'id'         => 2,
                               'parent'     => 1
                             ),
                3   => array ( 'id'         => 3,
                               'parent'     => 2
                             )
                );


function searchItem($needle,$haystack) {
    $nodes = array();
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $item) {
        if ($item['parent'] == $needle) {
            $nodes[$key] = $item;
            $nodes = $nodes + searchItem($item['id'],$haystack);
        }
    }
    return $nodes;
}


$result = searchItem('1',$nodes);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Non-recursive version of the searchItem() function:

```
function searchItem($needle,$haystack) {
    $nodes = array();
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $item) {
        if (($item['parent'] == $needle) || array_key_exists($item['parent'],$nodes)) {
            $nodes[$key] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $nodes;
}
```

(assumes ordering of the parents/children, so a child node isn't included in the array unless the parent is already there)

Comment: Hi mark! Thanks for your help! How would you modify it to be able to deal with finding multi-level children's?

Comment: To explain, if I run the function on the array in my example on the top node, I want to have both node 2&3 returned, since they both children to the top node, but on multiple levels.

Comment: The second one doesn't work as intended, does it? I only get one result back.

Comment: It produces the same results as the first (recursive) function using the same initial array as shown in my code, but won't return the correct results if a child is defined in the array before its parent

Comment: @Industrial I've removed my post. While you *can* do it with SPL, it does overcomplicate things for your UseCase. Mark's solution is fine. *Keep it Simple*.

Comment: Alright Gordon, thanksa a lot for your time. I will check out SPL in the future. Should be good to learn :)
Big ups to Mark baker for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function searchItem($needle)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $item)
    {
        if ($item['id'] == $needle)
        {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! Im afraid that you misunderstood me though. I need the children nodes to a specific "id"

Comment: I don't understand. Can you supply an example?

Comment: Updated original post. Thanks for your interest :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `array_walk_recursive()` function in PHP:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php